# How to get all values in a data table

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get all the values in a JavaScript data table but whenever I try it says, *"table.length is not a function"* or, *"table.size is not a function"* (I've tried both).

Here is  the code I want to use:

```js
const wordcount = {"this", "is", "a", "data", "table"}

console.log(wordcount.size()) // wordcount.size is not a function
```

I want it to return an integer value to the console. How would I do this?

Comment: That is not a valid object.

Comment: `wordcount = ["this", "is", "an", "array"]` and it has `wordcount.length` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const wordcount = {"this", "is", "a", "data", "table"};` is not a valid object.

You can use make it an array and get the array length by using the `length` property.

```js
const wordcount = ["this", "is", "a", "data", "table"];
console.log(wordcount.length); // 5
```

Or, create a proper object and get the size of the object's properties by using `Object.keys` which returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names, and then getting that length.

```js
const wordcount = {
        first: "this", second: "is", third: "a", forth: "data", fifth:"table"
    };
    
    console.log(Object.keys(wordcount).length); // 5
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first line, Object's type is not true.

If you want to loop object, here is sample code.

```
// Object Loop
const wordcount = {
    key1: "this", 
    key2: "is", 
    key3: "a", 
    key4: "data", 
    key5: "table"
}
for (let key in wordcount) {
    console.log(wordcount[key])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Word count is not an valid array, see the code below it should work fine

```
const wordCount = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'data', 'table']

console.log(wordCount.length)
```

An array should always start with this '[' and end with this ']' not with '{'

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your question wrong are you trying to make a data table?
A data table must only contain primitive values such as string, number, Boolean, null, undefined  etc.

```
// sample code 
const data = {
   name: "Jhon",
   age: 25,
   isChild: false,
 }
```

**Note**: size is not a function it is an attribute